# responsive full page banner using object fit cover

Tags: responsive, banner

I am using object-fit:cover. But it crops my image. I want my image to appear the same on all resolutions without cropping. Currently it gets cut from the sides. I want it to appear as a full page without any cropping.

```css
body,html{ height:100%;}

#home{ height:100vh;}
#home img{ height:100vh; width:100%; object-fit:cover;}
```

```html
<div id="home">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHmdc.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fill the whole page, use `object-fit:fill`. See [object-fit documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: But its getting cropped from sides.

Comment: Using fillits getting bit stretch..any more fix for the same

Comment: The image will only fit perfectly when the aspect ratio of the image is the same as the aspect ratio of the screen. In many cases the aspect ratio will differ so you'll have to choose whether the image will be cropped, stretched or only partially cover the background.
You can use the img/@srcset to choose a different image based on media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images